# How to mail a screen captured image using corona SDK

Tags: email, email-attachments, coronasdk, screen-capture

I am new to corona SDK, but I've managed to capture my app scene using the following code:

```
local function captureArea()
    local myCaptureImage = display.captureBounds(display.currentStage.contentBounds, true)
    myCaptureImage:removeSelf()
    myCaptureImage = nil
end
bg:addEventListener("tap",captureArea)
```

This works perfectly.

Now I need to send the captured image(with a specific name, say: `screen_1.png`) to my friend via email. I've used [Composing E-mail and SMS](http://www.coronalabs.com/blog/2012/01/03/composing-email-and-sms-in-corona/) for refference, but I fail to understand how I can add this saved image in the `attachment` field of mail options.

Please give me a proper solution that how can I attach and send the above saved image via email.

Comment: Are you sure, you can save captured images to temproray directory or documents directory ? I've done similar capture function before but I didn't use captureBounds function
I guess you should use display.save( view, "screen_1.png", system.DocumentsDirectory), where view represents display group that you want to save. After saving to documents directory, you can use composing e mail tutorial

Comment: @DoğancanArabacı: yes man, the above code is perfectly working. I have tested it. And thanks for the suggestion tooooooo...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`display.captureBounds` is good for saving the whole screen to the directory. But it usually saves the file with increase in last index. So it may be difficult to read them correctly. So I prefer `display.save`. But it is not a straight way.

For doing this, you have to:

- First create a  `localgroup`.
- Then `add` the screen objects to that group.
- `Return` the display group
- Use `display.save` to save the entire group displayed.
- Create mail option and add `attachment` image from `baseDirectory`
- Call `mail Popup`

I am giving a sample here:

```
-- creating the display group --
local localGroup = display.newGroup()  

-- creating display objects and adding it to the group --
local bg = display.newRect(0,0,_w,_h)
bg.x = 160
bg.y = 240
bg:setFillColor(150)
localGroup:insert(bg)

local rect = display.newRect(0,0,50,50)
rect.x = 30+math.random(260)
rect.y = 30+math.random(420)
localGroup:insert(rect)

-- Then do as follows --
local function takePhoto_andSendMail()
  -- take screen shot to baseDirectory --
  local baseDir = system.DocumentsDirectory
  display.save( localGroup, "myScreenshot.jpg", baseDir )

  -- Create mail options --
  local options =
  {
    to = { "krishnarajsalim@gmail.com",},
    subject = "My Level",
    body = "Add this...",
    attachment =
    {
      { baseDir=system.DocumentsDirectory, filename="myScreenshot.jpg", type="image" },
    },
  }

  -- Send mail --
  native.showPopup("mail", options)
end
rect:addEventListener("tap",takePhoto_andSendMail)
```

This will do it...

Keep coding........ :)