# How do I call the function of sending a email in this code in corona?

Tags: lua, coronasdk

Below is part of the code of a simple game i'm writing, I'm trying to send a email which contains the time that the users spent at the menu screen. I'm not sure where to call options function.

```
--Send a email to my own address
local options =
{
to = "richard@gmail.com",
subject = "Time spent at the menu screen",
body = "This is the time I spent to look at the menu"..(os.time() - startTime),
}
native.showPopup("mail", options)

--Function that initializes all game logic
function Main()
splash:removeSelf()
splash = nil

playGame = display.newImage("Play Button.png")
tutorial = display.newImage("Tutorial Button.png")
credits = display.newImage("Credits Button.png")

playGame.x = display.contentWidth / 2
playGame.y = display.contentWidth - 187
tutorial.x = display.contentWidth / 2
tutorial.y = display.contentWidth - 130
credits.x = display.contentWidth / 2
credits.y = display.contentWidth - 73

startButtonListeners('add')
end

--Adds listeners to the button in menu screen
function startButtonListeners(action)
    if (action == 'add') then
          playGame:addEventListener ('tap', showGameView)
          credits: addEventListener ('tap', showCredits)
          tutorial: addEventListener ("tap", showTutorial)
    else 
        playGame:removeEventListener ('tap', showGameView)
        print("Time spent at menu screen: ", (os.time() - startTime))
        credits: removeEventListener ('tap', showCredits)
        tutorial: removeEventListener ('tap', showTutorial)
          end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was not able to fully understand your need. I think, you have to send e-mail to a specific address when you left the screen or the game is over. So, when your game is over, or when you leave the screen by triggering a button, you can call a function with `options` inside that. Just like below:

```
local function sendMail()
   local options =
   {
     to = "richard@gmail.com",
     subject = "Time spent at the menu screen",
     body = "This is the time I spent to look at the menu"..(os.time() - startTime),
    }
    native.showPopup("mail", options)
end

...
...
...
sendMail()  -- Call this when the game is over/before you leave the scene
```

For more info, refer this link too: [How to mail a screen captured image using corona SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17752494/how-to-mail-a-screen-captured-image-using-corona-sdk/17780473#17780473)

Keep Coding............. :)

Comment: Thanks, this is wt i'm looking for. Btw, is there a way to test rather the code works on computer? I ran the code but it seems nothing happened and i can't find the email.

Comment: The corona native mail popup won't work on corona simulator. You have to build either build for Xcode simulator or for device to test it...